# Matlab Draw a line of pixels (Vector to Raster image)

Tags: matlab

Really basic, I have a series of points while will create a line. I would like to turn that line into a series of pixels on a plane

```
x = [10 33 50];
y = [50 30 9];

imshow(BW); hold on;
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

I originally had an idea of drawing the line by using poly2mask and expand it by drawing the line  from a 90 angle.

```
scalefactor = .08;

X1 = XData(1,1) - scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,1));
X2 = XData(1,1) + scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,1));
X3 = XData(1,2) + scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,1));
X4 = XData(1,3) + scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,3));
X5 = XData(1,3) - scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,3));
X6 = XData(1,2) - scalefactor*abs(YData(1,2) - YData(1,1));

Y1 = YData(1,1) - scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,1));
Y2 = YData(1,1) + scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,1));
Y3 = YData(1,2) + scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,1));
Y4 = YData(1,3) + scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,3));
Y5 = YData(1,3) - scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,3));
Y6 = YData(1,2) - scalefactor*abs(XData(1,2) - XData(1,1));

Xvect = [X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6];
Yvect = [Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6];

Lineimg = poly2mask(Xvect,Yvect,400,500);
```

Problem with this was that if the line turned upside down, it would pretty much disappear. Now I'm thinking of just drawing a line of pixels and then diluting it. Question is how to draw the line.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean... What's wrong with the example image you've given? Are you trying to edit the actual image data/matrix to include a line? Do you want to plot a line on an image and then export the result? Please try and clarify what you want the end result to be, it confuses me when you go on to talk about turning the line upside down and diluting it too.

Comment: I'm trying to rasterize the line. Right now it is a vector but I need it to be a raster line so I can feed it into my code. I know that **poly2mask** can turn vector data into raster data but I don't know if it can do the same thing for a simple line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry for the inconvenience. I personally admire the founder of MATLAB who develops a toolbox from a teaching aid and who shares it with his students to build a company. The basic idea of MATLAB is building mathematical models. So, I think mathematical model is the key.

We continue the story, and We will load a built-in figure and draw a line on it.

```
I = imread('peppers.png');
```

Then, three points are given.

```
x = [173 206 347];
y = [0 192 384];
```

We consider whether a line can pass these points. If you randomly choose three points in a plane, generically, they are non-collinear. This is called in general position. However, an arc can do this job. We fit these points with an arc.

```
Trial>> p = polyfit(x,y,1);
```

P is the mathematical model of the line that you want. The X coordinate of the line that we are about to draw is from zero to 521 which equals the figure.

```
Line_x1 = [0 521];
```

The mathematical model p is used to calculate the Y coordinates.

```
Line_y1 = polyval(p,Line_x1);
```

Now we have enough information to draw the line.

```
RGB = insertShape(I,'Line',[Line_x1(1) Line_y1(1) Line_x1(2) Line_y1(2)],'LineWidth',5);
imshow(RGB);
```

It is not exactly pass the given points; however, it is the line that is nearest these points from in the viewpoint of the polynomial curve fitting.

[image]

Comment: Does exactly what I need. Thanks a bunch. I didn't know that the function **insertShape** existed and was trying to use polyfit.

Answer (score 0):

We consider whether a line can pass these points.

If you randomly choose three points in a plane, generically, they are non-collinear. This is called in general position. However, an arc can do this job. We fit these points with an arc.

```
Trial>> x = [10 33 50];
Trial>> y = [50 30 9];
Trial>> p = polyfit(x,y,1);
```

P is the mathematical model of the line that you want. The next is to generate pixels. Suppose that we want the x coordinates of pixels vary from ten to fifteen.

```
x1 = linspace(10,50);
```

With the mathematical model p, we calculate the y coordinates of pixels.

```
y1 = polyval(p,x1);
```

Now, we draw the generated pixels and the given points together to see the result.

```
plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
hold off
```

[image]

It is not exactly pass the given points; however, it is the line that is nearest these points from in the viewpoint of the polynomial curve fitting.

Comment: thanks for the reply. From what it looks like though is that the line is still portrayed as a vector when I really need it to be a raster graphic